# Typed text not getting removed from kartik select2 after seleting option

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-widget

Hi i am using kartik select2 in my yii application. The select box for selecting multiple options is working fine. However i am facing one small issue.
[image]

Like if i type ba then it will display all matching options. but when i press enter then Bakam get selected but the text ba remains in select box. It should get removed.
[image]

Here is code for my select box

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'area')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => [],
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Location'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'closeOnSelect' => false,
                        'tags' => false,
                        'multiple' => true,
                    ],
                ])->label("Reassign Location")
                ?>
```

I checked it on kartik website the code seems fine then why the text remains there?

Comment: Have you checked console? Do you see any errors?

Comment: No error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set  `'closeOnSelect' => true,` in pluginOptions to remove selected option.